# Using jqGrid with HTML5 local database

Tags: javascript, html, jqgrid

I would like to use jqGrid for a pretty large HTML5/SQLite application. All of the data will be local and I'll never be calling a server. I've build a pretty simple bridge class that sort of hijacks the normal server-client communication by setting the `url` to `'#'` capturing the changed data with `afterSubmit` but it is very, very hacky. Is there a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since jqGrid 3.7 there is

```
selector.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    ...
    });
```

combination of parameters, that allows you to specify your own data. `mydata` here is an array of rows in form `{"id":1,"mycol1":"val1"...}`

[jqgrid demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)  - look into "New in version 3.7" - "Load data array at once"

You will also need to implement your own reloading mechanism.