# JQGrid update multiple rows at once then save

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a requirement to be able to update `'n'` number of rows in one go.

I have acheived this by adding a `SELECT` into the column header of 1 particular column. This will give the user the option of picking a Yes/No option and making all subsuequent rows in said particular column in the grid view, the choice of Yes or No dependant on which the user chooses.

I have successfuly managed to do this. My problem is now sending the "New" updated row data to the server.

I have tried `saveRow()` with the row id of each row in the view. This does not do anything. No `AJAX` calls are made.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write the answer only because you asked to point you in the right direction. Sending of the data from the local grid to the server is not complex (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800440/315935) for example). The main problem is the case is concurrency.

In my opinion any web application should work not only as one user application. I wrote multiple answers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943297/315935) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6640515/315935) for example) where I described my opinion that one should better update modified rows directly after modification because of possible concurrency errors. The later the update take place the higher is the possibility that the same rows were already modified by another user from another computer. So I would recommend you to use standard `saveRow` behavior and send modified data directly after the modification.

Comment: there are many ways to control concurrency like sql server time span (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/917040/how-to-use-the-timestamp-column-of-a-table-for-optimistic-concurrency) or many other methods that you can use so if you do it right it wont be a problem.

Comment: @PouyaSamie: Independent from the way in which control concurrency is implemented one have the same problem. Let us the user try to save only **one** row, and the concurrency error is detected. Then the user have to reload the grid (with more recent data) and repeat the changes in the row. If one would implement saving of *multiple* rows at once then some from the rows could be already modified and some other not modified. You will have to display much more complex error message and  the user have to repeat much more changes which he/she done before. Saving one row is more simple as multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by simply making an AJAX call myself to the file that is declared in JQGrid. Passing all relevant data everything worked how I needed it to