# jqGrid need to perform default action of onPaging event after executing custom function

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid in which when I click on the next/previous page, I want to execute some custom function (which saves the uncommitted changes done using inline editing) and once that function finishes execution, I want the default action of onPaging event to execute (i.e. load next page data).

```
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    clickedSaveAll = false;
    BulkSave();
}
```

**Actual output : The default action triggers before the custom function.** 
Please help.

Comment: why not save the rows after the user edit? ref @Oleg answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943297/330606

Comment: @PauloDiogo Thanks for your reply. This is a client requirement as they are using jqGrid as a person would use excel workbook (I know that sounds weird.) So any help on how to achieve the give problem statement.

Comment: save the row on server side when the user leave each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not full clear what you do inside of `BulkSave`. It's important to understand that `onPaging` callback should work **synchronously**. If you need to make some asynchronous Ajax call to the server for example that you can do the following:

1. you can analyse `pgButton` value to calculate which page will be loaded as "default action" of paging.
2. you can use `return "stop";` as the last statement of `onPaging` callback. It *prevents* default actions.
3. you can include `.trigger("reloadGrid", {page: savedPage});` at the end of your custom action `BulkSave`. It will simulates "default action" of paging *after* your custom action will be finished.

Comment: thank you for your reply. This solution works perfectly for me. Sorry for the delayed reply as I was away for sometime. 
I just wanted to know if we an do something to stop the refresh event as well? Also I want to the same thing for Edit option as well. Please help.

Comment: Thanks once again. For reload button... I have removed the jqGrid default and replaced it with custom button.